# Solve $n(n+1)=m(m+1) \bmod 2^N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to solve $n(n+1)=m(m+1) \bmod 2^N$ in the range of $1\leq n ,m < 2^N$ and $n \neq m$.
One of the solution is $m=2^N-n-1$.

Is there any other solution (numerical calculation says No. 
I want to prove this. )?

Comment: What about $m=n$?

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguous statement. I add the condition, $n\neq m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your relation is the same as $$(n+m+1)(n-m) \equiv0$$

One of $n+m+1$, $n-m$ is odd. The even one must be divisible by $2^N$. So either:

- $n+m+1=k\cdot2^N$, in which case $m=k\cdot2^N-n-1$, or
- $n-m=k\cdot2^N$, in which case $m=k\cdot2^N+n$

Given the additional constraints that $1\leq m,n<2^N$, either $k=1$ in the first case above, or $k=0$ in the second. But that last one makes $m=n$, which is also not within the specification. So yes, the only solution meeting all the criteria is $m=2^N-n-1$.